# shared_ptr of barrier doesn't keep the expected counter

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++20, barrier

I have 2 code examples syncing 2 threads with `std::barrier{2}`. In one I create the barrier statically, and in one I create it dynamically. The 2nd way mimics the way I want to use the barrier - since number of threads - and hence the "size" of the barrier, is something I'll know only on runtime, making it impossible to declare it static.

My question is - why the static snippet works, where the dynamic snippet (using shared pointers) doesn't (it just hangs...)

My snippets are compiled and run with: `clang++-15 -l pthread --std=c++20 demo.cpp && ./a.out` (I've also used `g++-11`)

Updated (3rd snippet working! :) )

```
#include <barrier>
#include <functional>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

// Working
// static std::barrier b{2};

// int task() {
// b.arrive_and_wait();
// std::cout << "start\n";
// b.arrive_and_wait();
// std::cout << "stop\n";
// return 0;
//}

// int main() {
// std::vector<std::future<int>> promises;
// for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
// auto promise = std::async(task);
// promises.push_back(std::move(promise));  // Why must I use std::move?
//}
// for (auto& promise : promises) {
// std::cout << promise.get() << std::endl;
//}
// return 0;
//}

// Not working (1) - reference
// int task(std::barrier<std::function<void()>>& b) {
// std::cout << "start\n";
// b.arrive_and_wait();
// std::cout << "stop\n";
// b.arrive_and_wait();
// return 0;
//}

// int main() {
// std::vector<std::future<int>> promises;
// std::barrier<std::function<void()>> barrier{2};

// for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
// auto promise = std::async(task, std::ref(barrier));
// promises.push_back(std::move(promise));  // Why must I use std::move?
//}
// for (auto& promise : promises) {
// std::cout << promise.get() << std::endl;
//}
// return 0;
//}

// Working!!
int task(std::shared_ptr<std::barrier<>> b) {
  std::cout << "start\n";
  b->arrive_and_wait();
  std::cout << "stop\n";
  b->arrive_and_wait();
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  std::vector<std::future<int>> promises;
  auto barrier = std::make_shared<std::barrier<>>(2);

  for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    auto promise = std::async(task, barrier);
    promises.push_back(std::move(promise));  // Why must I use std::move?
  }
  for (auto& promise : promises) {
    std::cout << promise.get() << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: your problem may be that `shared_ptr` is not thread safe.

Comment: I'm guessing it's because you're attempting to call an uninitialized `std::function`.  Try using `std::barrier<>` instead of `std::barrier<std::function<void()>>` or initializing the completion function when you create the barrier.

Comment: @blankettripod Also tried it with `std::ref` which is thread safe and it still didn't work

Comment: @MilesBudnek Wow! I'm working half a day on this - and your solution just worked! so simple. Can you explain? Also - how come this works if, as @blankettripod said - `shared_ptr` isn't thread safe

Comment: I don't think thread-safety is a problem here since you never try to modify the `shared_ptr` while its being used by another thread.  `share_ptr` isn't _fully_ thread-safe, but its ref counter is atomic, so passing it between threads like this should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempting to call a default-initialized `std::function`.

Your two examples use different `CompletionFunction` types.

- `std::barrier b{2}` uses the default `CompletionFunction` type, which is an unspecified DefaultConstructible function that does nothing.
- `std::make_shared<std::barrier<std::function<void()>>>` use `std::function<void()>` as its `CompletionFunction` type, which while DefaultConstructible, will throw an exception if you attempt to call it without giving it a callable to wrap.

Since you never initialize your `std::barrier`'s `CompletionFunction` and `std::barrier`'s `CompletionFunction` isn't allowed to throw exceptions, you get undefined behavior.

---

(Technically I think it's undefined behavior to use `std::function` as the `CompletionFunction` type at all, since `std::is_nothrow_invocable_v<std::function<void()>&>` is `false`)

Comment: Many thanks - Just so I get it fully - the function I declared in the template (`std::function<void()`) does not guarantee `nothrow` and so, for some reason it did throw an exception which crashed my app? If this is true then I'm still missing 2 things: 1) why did it throw? it is an empty function. 2) if it threw an exception, why my app hung  but didn't abort? was it because my main thread was still running?

Comment: @CIsForCookies 1) You can think of `std::function` as a container that can hold any type of callable matching a particular interface.  If you try to call it without putting anything in the container (which you didn't, in this case), it will throw an exception (as documented [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator())).

Comment: @CIsForCookies 2) Because you violated `std::barrier`'s preconditions (that its completion function doesn't throw), its behavior is undefined.  In this case, the thread running the completion function likely crashed, leaving the other `async` task waiting on some lock that will never get released, and the main thread waiting for a promise that will never resolve.  That's not guaranteed though.  Anything can happen, from crashing to hanging to making demons fly out of your nose.